# Uploading documents to CouchDB in pure JS

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cloudant

I'm writing a game in a web browser, and I'd like to make a highscores list. I'd like it to save highscores so users can compete, so I've created a database in Cloudant (CouchDB) to which I plan to upload & download the scores.

```
function uploadHighscores() {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('PUT', 'http://reverse-snake.cloudant.com/highscores/highscores', true); // METHOD, url, async
  req.onload = function() { // Asynchronous callback.
    console.log(req.responseText);
    console.log("Scores uploaded");
  }
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log("Sending scores...");

  req.send("{\"_id\": \"highscores\", \"_rev\": \"6-f29fd233a21c65e3f4a7485f36c46ae4\", \"data\":{\"scores\":[999, 999, 999, 999, 999], \"times\":[[59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999]]}}");
}
```

This fails with the error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://reverse-snake.cloudant.com/highscores/highscores. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

I've tried doing this request with curl:

```
curl http://reverse-snake.cloudant.com/highscores/highscores -X PUT -d "{\"_id\": \"highscores\", \"_rev\": \"6-f29fd233a21c65e3f4a7485f36c46ae4\", \"data\":{\"scores\":[999, 999, 999, 999, 999], \"times\":[[59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999], [59, 59, 999]]}}"
```

and it succeeds. What am I missing?

Edit: Per request, the log of the failed http request: http://pastebin.com/D97KwpM1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is painfully simple. CouchDB (and Cloudant) require secure network access. This was revealed by the network logs:

Get requests went to http://... and were replied with a redirect; this lead to https://...

Put requests went to http://... and were replied with a redirect; this lead to a failure.

The only change that needs to be made is on line 2, changing the method. Setting request headers is not required.

Comment: When you say "changing the method", you mean https instead of http ? If you remove the `setRequestHeader`, you also remove the preflight, so this should also allow redirects, right ?

Comment: Changing the protocol to https works with or without setRequestHeader.

Comment: Yes https works, what is not clear is the 2nd part of the question "why the http redirect on PUT is working with curl". My understanding was that removing the `setRequestHeader` should remove the CORS preflight that makes the redirect fail. That's not the case, so I guess that all PUT requests are preflighted by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is CORS-related, and curl bypasses that check (it's a "security" feature, but the checking is done by the browser, so the security is quite weak).

**EDIT** The error occurs because of a http => https redirect. The redirect can be avoided, see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35245820/5695504), but why is it failing from the browser ?

Here is the network log:

```
Request URL:http://reverse-snake.cloudant.com/highscores/highscores
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:307 Internal Redirect
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:null
Location:https://reverse-snake.cloudant.com/highscores/highscores
Non-Authoritative-Reason:HSTS
```

The explanation is that in the CORS machinery, in some cases, the browser first sends an OPTIONS ("preflight") request to get some capability informations from the server. A PUT request has a mandatory preflight, a GET request hasn't. That OPTIONS request can't be redirected.

Comment: I know CORS is working, because A. I enabled it on Cloudant and B. I can do GET requests in the browser successfully.

Comment: CouchDB uses the _rev property to handle document conflicts. If a PUT (or POST) request is sent without this property, CouchDB will not allow the document to be uploaded.

Comment: "I can do GET requests in the browser successfully" => to your DB ? How are you doing them ?

Comment: req.open('GET', 'http://reverse-snake.cloudant.com/highscores/highscores', true);

Comment: "If a PUT (or POST) request is sent without this property, CouchDB will not allow the document to be uploaded" => That would be terribly inconvenient, did you try an insert without `_rev` ?

Comment: When I send such a request with curl, I get 409 Conflict (as expected, it refuses the upload). When I send such a request via js, I get the same error.

Comment: "I get 409 Conflict" => OK, for an update. I was thinking of document creation - where `_rev` is set by the DB.

Comment: Do you allow all domains in your CORS config ? Did you try commenting out the `setRequestHeader` ?

Comment: Cors is currently enabled for all domains. I've tried removing that header line, as well as adding all the lines that appear when I run curl --verbose.

Comment: OK, but somehow the browser thinks that the server's preflight answer is incorrect. Could you add the server's response that your browser is logging ?

Comment: Unsure as to what you mean.